# how to open and WRQ relection program through VB script?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vbscript, vb6

I want to open test.r2w file  (r2w is extention for WRQ reflection program) and then i want to run macro which is store inside of that file and then i want to close it automatically.

is it possible through any vbscript or any batch file?

If not some could please help me to open this program and file through excel macro?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for this WRQ reflection program, whatever that is. Does it support COM automation? Then, use CreateObject() and COM methods.

Otherwise, does it support command line running of this file? Then use Shell "" to run the macro.

Otherwise ... probably not.